# Verifying adoption of ancestor born 1816 in Tennessee, USA?

Tags: united-states, adoption, tennessee, 1810s

I have a great grandmother who was born in 1816.

Her name was Elizabeth G Smith Armstrong, born in Tennessee, and maybe married to William Armstrong who died in Yolo County California.

In 1862 she was told that she could have been adopted.

How could I try to verify that?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If her maiden name was Smith (can you confirm) then I think it may be very difficult to trace her at all.  Why do you only say "maybe married to William Armstrong"?  Perhaps a question focussed on establishing the birth family of her child (your grandfather or grandmother) may be more fruitful first.